# SPNE of a normal form game

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

If we have a sequential game which is equivalent to a simultaneous move game because of its information structure, then the NE we find are also SPNE?

Comment: What does "equivalent to a simultaneous move game because of its information structure" mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you draw the corresponding game tree, you will see that "equivalent to simultaneous move game" implies that the game has no proper subgame and the only subgame is the whole game.
This is because the information set of the second player covers every move of the first player.
Therefore, every Nash equilibrium is trivially also subgame perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. There are no proper subgames then, so all NE are trivially SP.

Answer (score 3):

If a sequential game can be validly represented in the 'normal form' then that means the game has only one sub-game - the whole game. In that case any NE is also SPNE.